# Execute stored procedure using entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

is it possible to execute a stored procedure using EF, that select records from database from two or more tables using inner join and left outer join.

my point of view is to avoid the method of doing joins in EF or LINQ, which i have many issues with it.

so if i create that procedure, can i call it with parameters from user input, can  assign the result to `.ToList()` method and then add the result to asp:repeater `.DataSource`.

I know it may be a strange question, but i want to do this for many reasons
first, to use EF because i feel more comfortable.
second, to get rid of using joins in EF.
third, i read somewhere that using stored procedure will enhance query performance, when used to  call a query frequently.

if any one could help me to answer these questions with an example i would be appreciate.

Comment: both sql-server and mysql? also is EF it code first ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can call `SqlQuery` from your Entity Framework data context.

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<YourType>("exec usp_StoredProcedure").ToList()
```

You would need a class to map the query results back, as an example:

```
public class YourType
{
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can also specify parameters to the query as shown below:

```
SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", "Value");
context.Database.SqlQuery<YourType>("exec usp_StoredProcedure @Parameter1", parameter1).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes I know that @darren but in my situation calling this query is very complex and will be used frequently in my app, so i prefer to use SP calling.
my question here is how to call `.ToList()` method for the resul.

Comment: @FaresAyyad - I've gave the solution to execute a SP.  What appears to be the problem?

Comment: @DarrrenDavies what is the class to get the query results?

Comment: @FaresAyyad - You would have to make one which represents the columns you return from the stored procedure.  I've provided a dummy one for you called `YourType`

Comment: You know when you forget the syntax for doing simple things like this and have to Google it, and then you come across your old chum Darren... :)

Answer (score 0):

We are going to see how to execute the stored procedure in Entity Framework, in MVC we are going to see the how to add the EF.

Execute the following script in the database to create a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FETCHEMPLOYEES AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EMPTABLE
END

CREATE PROCEDURE FETCHEMPLOYEE(@ID INT) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM EMPTABLE WHERE ID = @ID
END



public class EmpModel
{
    EmployeeEntities empdb = new EmployeeEntities();

    public List<EMPTABLE> GetEmployees()
    {
       return empdb.FETCHEMPLOYEES().ToList();  
    }

    public EMPTABLE GetEmployee(int? id)
    {
        return empdb.FETCHEMPLOYEE(id).ToList().Single();
    }
}

public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    Models.EmpModel mod = new Models.EmpModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<EMPTABLE> result = mod.GetEmployees();
        return View(result);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        EMPTABLE result = mod.GetEmployee(id);
        return View(result);
    }
}
```

For more step by step details, please refer following link:
http://dotnetvisio.blogspot.in/2014/01/execute-stored-procedure-using-entity.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ExecuteFunction` of `ObjectContext` class:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<CustomClassForStoreReturnedData> NameOfStoredProcedure(Nullable<int> tableID)
    {
        var IDParameter = tableID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("tableID", tableID) :
            new ObjectParameter("tableID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<CustomClassForStoreReturnedData>("NameOfStoredProcedureInSQLDatabase", IDParameter);
    }
```

Comment: @LeresAldtai i dont see OP say any thing about its approach

Answer (score 0):

**In you are using Entity Framework with MySQL:**

In this example, my stored procedure is expecting one parameter, named *myParam* of 
type *BIGINT*

```
var myParam = new SqlParameter("@myParam", (MySqlDbType.Int64)).Value = 100;

var res = _context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>($"call MyProcedureName({pyParam})");
```

Note that I am using [C# String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) to build my query string.