# Return output from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

With the naked select I get the proper iden

```
declare @iden table (pk int);

update top (1) lockDate with (UPDLOCK) 
set dt = GETDATE()
output inserted.iden into @iden   
where dt is null 

select top (1) iden.pk
from @iden iden;
```

When I try and put it in a stored procedure I always get a 0.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
DROP PROCEDURE addLockDate

CREATE PROCEDURE addLockDate
AS  
    DECLARE @iden TABLE (pk INT);

    UPDATE TOP (1) lockDate WITH (UPDLOCK) 
    SET dt = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT inserted.iden INTO @iden   
    WHERE dt IS NULL

    RETURN SELECT TOP (1) iden.pk
           FROM @iden iden
GO
```

Comment: Try putting the final SELECT in parens?   That, or use an intervening variable.

Comment: Update top 1???

Comment: @SeanLange Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: Remove "return" from the procedure

Comment: Is that even valid syntax? And how would it know which row to update? It would need an order by which I would guess is not valid in an update statement. Something seems a bit off here to me.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin that would necessitate changing the way the return value is consumed which may or may not be an option.

Comment: @SeanLange As stated "With the naked select I get the proper iden".

Comment: @TabAlleman That worked if you want to post and answer.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Did not work

Comment: No offense meant but it must be by luck. Top with no order by has no way of determining what row will be updated. If it doesn't matter which row is updated then this is probably ok but that is rarely the case.

Comment: You should read this article. You are counting on the order of returned data with no order by. It will likely work for awhile, but not forever. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: @SeanLange I am not counting on the order of the returned data.  It works and does what I need.

Comment: OK. Not sure how using top is not counting on the order. But whatever, there are probably some other pieces not clear here. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @SeanLange I am not top.  Is that hard to believe I just need a /any record that is null?

Comment: aside from all the comments its always a good idea to start stored procedures with `SET NOCOUNT ON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this might work:

```
drop PROCEDURE addLockDate
CREATE PROCEDURE addLockDate
AS  
    declare @iden table (pk int);
    update top (1) lockDate with (UPDLOCK) 
       set dt = GETDATE()
    output inserted.iden into @iden   
    where dt is null 
    return (select top (1) iden.pk
    from @iden iden);
GO
```

This would definitely work:

```
drop PROCEDURE addLockDate
CREATE PROCEDURE addLockDate
AS  
    declare @iden table (pk int);
    declare @outint int;
    update top (1) lockDate with (UPDLOCK) 
       set dt = GETDATE()
    output inserted.iden into @iden   
    where dt is null 
    set @outint = (select top (1) iden.pk
    from @iden iden);
    return @outint;
GO
```